# How to handle missing data (when items not present) in IRT analysis in R

Tags: r, missing-data, item-response-theory

I am trying to calibrate an Item bank using IRT 2PL analysis in R. I have 60 dichotomous Items in my bank, while at any given instance a random set of 25 items are presented to a test taker. I have been able to compute difficulty and discrimination parameters for them (using ltm and mirt packages), whereas I am not able to obtain person ability parameters because there is missing data in each row. I need to standardize this item bank and develop norms so that I can compare performance of the future test takers with this standardization group. How can I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean you can't compute ability parameters because of missing data? What happens when you pass your model to `mirt`'s `fscores()` function? All the missing data does, assuming MAR, is reduce the potential precision of the latent trait predictions (i.e,., you'll see larger standard errors for responses with missing data than you would for individuals with the same ability who took all items).

Comment: @philchalmers thanks for the tip. It worked. I was making the error of keeping na.rm=TRUE, which was problematic as I had missing data in each row. Now can you help me identify item weights which I can use to derive norms for future comparisons?